# How to read a zipped CSV file using Java inside an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: java, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I had a requirement where I had to read a `.csv` file from S3 bucket. I achieved it through

```
S3Object s3Obj = amazonS3Client.getObject(bucketname, fileName);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Obj.getObjectContent()));
```

Now the same `.csv` file is in archived (zipped) form presented in AWS S3 bucket. I need to read this `.csv` file without unzip operations at my server-end.

Is there any documentation or API's present in AWS to read `.csv` file directly without unzipping it?

Comment: You could use a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read it.

Comment: Thanx for responding. ZipInputStream needs InputSream object. But have s3Object.

Comment: Following the the javadoc [S3Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) is a subclass of InputStream. So you could at least try it. If it fails you could post the error message here. ;-)

Comment: Here our s3Object is zipped file which has CSV file zipped in it. The method we can call on s3Object is getObjectContent() for reading stream of data. But if i call getObjectContent() directly on s3Object it gives un-intended data..

Answer (score 9):

You can read a zipped CSV file directly from Amazon S3 with these steps:

1. Get the object from S3
2. Create a ZipInputStream with the object's data
3. Create a Reader with the ZipInputStream

Example:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();  
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject("mybucket","myfile.csv.zip");  
ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(object.getObjectContent());  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Because a zip file can contain many files within you will need to position the ZipInputStream at the beginning of each ZipEntry to read each contained file individually. (Even if your zip file contains only one file within you will need to do this once to place the ZipInputStream at the beginning of the lone ZipEntry.)

```
String line;
while (in.getNextEntry() != null) { // loop through each file within the zip
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // loop through each line
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, should be the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If in your example `s3Obj.getObjectContent()` returns a ZIP compressed file stream, than something similar should work to access it.

```
ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(s3Obj.getObjectContent());
while ((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    System.out.printf("entry: %s%n", entry.getName());
}
in.close();
```

Comment: and if you are looking for the content of the csv file, how to proceed?

Comment: @NourdineAlouane To read the entry in the ZIP file usually `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName())` give you access to the stream.

Comment: entry.getName() doesn't work, if you have a file "test.zip" that contains "test.csv", endeed entry.getName() will return "test.csv" as a string. However the input stream name is something different than "test.csv", usually something like "fre4df9hg6f23s5kg6f3s9dhg.csv". This code worked for me, but it get access to the first GZIP entry:
`BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("YOUR GZIP FILE"))));
  String content;
  while ((content = in.readLine()) != null){
     System.out.println(content); 
     
  }`

Comment: @NourdineAlouane I don't use Amazons S3 service. Everthing was based on the information provided by the OP. I don't know anything about the S3Object structure. Maybe you should start from this point http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html.